# Exclude the www- append to only one multisite

Tags: 7, multi-sites, .htaccess

Stock Drupal 7 contains the following in the .htaccess file

```
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # uncomment the following:
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

As per client request, this works just dandy! However, on a multisite installation, one site wants to be excluded from this rule. I tried to get them to remove the auto-www-append, but alas, that failed.

So now I'm in a situation which some multisites (most of them) want the www appended and a small group doesn't want it.

**My question**: Can I exempt some sites from this rule? Can I throw these exceptions into an apache conf file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/www-exceptions.cnf` so that it's not overwritten in a core update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately putting separate htaccess files in each sites folder doesnt work, otherwise it would be quite straight forward.

Perhaps you can use REWRITECOND to do this?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} yourclientsdomain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```